# Elemento Pai Height e Elementos Filhos Position Absolute

Tags: css, less

Tenho uma `div` - `position:relative`. E dentro dessa `div` tenho várias `divs`- `position:absolute`.

Dessa forma o `height` da `div` pai não funciona automaticamente.

Eu quero que o `height` ajuste automaticamente ao posicionamento dos elementos absolutos. Estou imaginando que não dê pra fazer isso mesmo.

Eu tenho que determinar um `height` fixo ? Tem algum **fix** para resolver isso ?

Estou usando LESS, galera. LESS!

```css
.mockup{
    padding-bottom: 70px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 270px;
    img{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
     }
}
```

Comment: Esse `img{` dentro de `.mockup{` funciona? Ou você publicou errado aqui?

Comment: Você está usando LESS ou SASS? Se estiver, por favor mencione isso na pergunta. Caso contrário, ver comentário do @Orion.

Comment: O que você quer dizer com `o height da div pai não funciona automaticamente`? Você quer que a imagem fique com a altura do `.mockup`?

Comment: Estou usando LESS.

Comment: @Oeslei, quero que a altura da `div` pai se ajuste ao passo que movimento os elementos absolutos. Eu eu der um `top:100px` quero que o `height` fique `100px`.

Comment: Estou com o mesmo problema, mas já vi que só com css não vai rolar mesmo não cara...
Se você conseguir resolver até eu to querendo saber e seu conseguir a resposta venho aqui colocar.... De qualquer jeito a melhor forma é usando JS mesmo...Poucas linhas solucionam...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Tem algum fix pra resolver isso?*

1. Com puro CSS, **NÃO**. Quem diz isso são os overlords do Mozilla, na sua [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position):

   > ...In contrast, an element that is positioned absolutely is taken out of the flow and thus takes up no space when placing other elements. The absolutely positioned element is positioned relative to nearest positioned ancestor. If a positioned ancestor doesn't exist, the initial container is used.

   Em uma tradução livre da parte que nos interessa: *um elemento que é posicionado absolutamente é retirado do flow e **não** ocupa espaço quando outros elementos são colocados*.

   Isto significa que, para todos os efeitos, um elemento absolutamente posicionado não existe para o seu pai, em termos de definição de altura ou largura do último, portanto suas dimensões não vão alterar as dimensões de outros elementos acima dele. `overflow: auto` e coisas do tipo não vão funcionar.
2. Com JS? **SIM**.

   Como você bem perguntou, isso é um *fix*, uma vez que você está tentando alcançar um objetivo com coisas que não foram feitas para tal.

   Fiz um [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g1ur7cz7/1/) pra demonstrar a "técnica". A idéia é basicamente somar o tamanho dos itens dentro da `div` pai, e atribuir o resultado como altura desta `div`.

   ```
   var blocks = $('.block').length;
   var altura = $('.block').height();
   altura *= blocks;
   $('.mockup').css('height', altura);
   ```

   No meu fiddle, os itens chamam-se `block`, pra facilitar um pouco as coisas. Se você adicionar ou retirar `.block`s do html, não se esqueça de aumentar ou diminuir a variável `$total` no `SCSS` de acordo, para que o `css` compilado não gere problemas. Novamente, isso é um *hack*. Você terá que adequar as coisas ao seu código. Se você estiver trabalhando com `box-sizing: border-box`, por exemplo, terá que levar em conta o tamanho das bordas no cálculo das alturas.

Comment: Entendi, Caio. Já que os elementos filhos absolutos são 'rebeldes',  não faz diferença eu mudar o `height` do elemento Pai na unha ? Porquê fico pensando nas posições dos elementos absolutos. Não quero que esses elementos fiquem relativos ao `body`, quero que fique relativo a esse elemento pai.

Comment: Depende de como você relacionar os dois. Se você coloca os filhos com `top: 10px`, eles vão estar sempre à 10px de distância do topo, independente da altura do bloco. Se, por outro lado, você faz `bottom: 10px`, ele vai estar a 10px do fundo, independente de onde esteja o fundo, o que pode alterar a posição *total* do bloco

Answer (score 3):

Seu css está errado, não pode colocar um elemento dentro do outro como você colocou, deveria ser assim:

```
.mockup{
    padding-bottom: 70px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 270px;
}
.mockup img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Eu não avisei. Estou programando em LESS. Mas mesmo assim, seu código não funcionaram para o que eu quero. Você definiu um `height` fixo.

Comment: `position:absolute` não irá alterar a altura da `div` pai, o que você pode fazer é usar `float` para colocar as `div` internas lado a lado e ir aumentando a altura a medida que uma nova `div` é inserida automaticamente.

Comment: Não posso. Tem que ser absolute. É um mockup, é elemento em cima de elemento...