# Como restringir a largura de um elemento div absoluto dentro de um outro div, mantendo sua posição?

Tags: css

Eu gostaria de criar um elemento `div` com largura dinâmica, e outro elemento `div` dentro deste com a propriedade `position: absolute e width: 100%`, mas sem que esse `div` de dentro passe "por cima" do `div` pai.

A imagem abaixo demonstra o que preciso, no primeiro exemplo o que eu tenho, e no segundo o que quero.

[image: Exemplo]

Eu já consegui fazer isso algumas vezes, mas nunca entendi o porque ora funciona e ora não. Quando que um `div` absoluto com 100% de largura vai ocupar 100% da página, e quando que ele vai ocupar 100% da área disponível (`div` pai)?

Obs: Eu **preciso** que este elemento `div` de dentro seja absoluto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `div` com `position: absolute` tem o posicionamento absoluto sempre referente à `div` pai que tem posicionamento relativo. Se nenhuma `div` pai tem posicionamento relativo, o posicionamento dela será absoluto com relação ao corpo, ou seja, `width: 100%` vai ser 100% da largura da tag `body`.

```css
.relative{
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: black;
}

.absolute{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  top:50px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
  <div class="absolute">Teste</div>
</div>
```

Experimente retirar `position: relative` de `.relative` pra você ver o que acontece.

[Nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/68504/23051) dou mais detalhes de como o posicionamento absoluto funciona.

**EDIT**

Vale lembrar que `div.absolute` é absoluta com relação à *primeira* `div` que contém `position: relative` que se encontra em *qualquer* nível acima no DOM, não necessariamente o seu pai direto. Isso quer dizer que a relação `div.relative > div.absolute` não precisa necessariamente ser verdadeira. Outros elementos podem existir no meio dessa hierarquia. Para ilustrar:

```css
.relative{
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

.middle{
  background-color: red;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

.absolute{
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 75px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="absolute"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Veja que `.absolute` é relativa à `.relative`, ignorando `.middle`. Se `.middle` contivesse `position: relative`, `.absolute` seria relativa a `.middle`. Caso `position: relative` seja retirada de `.relative`, a faixa amarela vai ocupar 100% da janela (no caso atual, onde `.middle` não contém `.relative`).